# How do I display all multiples of the starting value for as many multiples as the 2nd parameter states?

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting the right output. I am trying to get my program to do the following: display all multiples of the starting value for as many multiples as the 2nd parameter states.

I don't understand why I am not getting the correct answers when I compile the program. Can someone explain what I did wrong and how to correct?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Proj3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int iNumMultiples;  //holds input by user 
        int iStartingValue; //holds input by user
        int iVal;           //holds the multiples

        System.out.print("\nEnter integer for multiples and the number of multiples: ");
        iStartingValue = kb.nextInt();
        iNumMultiples = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nThe first " + iNumMultiples + " multiples of " + iStartingValue + " are: " + iVal);
    }
}

public class MyMath
{
    //+displayMultiples(startingValue:int, numMultiples:int):void
    public static void displayMultiples(int startingValue, int numMultiples)
    {
        int Val = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<=numMultiples; i++)
        {
            Val += startingValue;
            System.out.print("\n" + Val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of quick things: (a) can you edit your question to include some sample input and output; (b) your `main()` method does not make use of your `MyMath` class.

Comment: When user is prompted for two integers lets say 2 and 5 the output says The first 5 multiples of 2 are 24. The MyMath class is in the same folder as the Proj3.

Comment: The presence of `MyMath` in the same folder as `Proj3` does not mean `MyMath` is automatically used. Wouldn't the first 5 multiples of 2 be 2, 4, 6, 8, 10?

Comment: You are **not** calling the method `displayMultiples`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kb is, you haven't defined it. You actually have to call your displayMultiples method. Not sure why you are breaking this into multiple classes.

```
public class MyProj {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int iNumMultiples;  //holds input by user 
    int iStartingValue; //holds input by user
    int iVal;           //holds the multiples

    //System.out.println("Enter integer for multiples and the number of multiples: ");
    iStartingValue = 5;
    iNumMultiples = 5;
    System.out.println("The first " + iNumMultiples + " multiples of " + iStartingValue);
    displayMultiples(iStartingValue, iNumMultiples);
}

//+displayMultiples(startingValue:int, numMultiples:int):void
public static void displayMultiples(int startingValue, int numMultiples)
{
    int val = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<=numMultiples; i++)
    {
        val += startingValue;
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I just took their example code. No, I'd normally use System.out.println to avoid having to add the \n. For projects I wouldn't use that anyway, you are better to use a logging system like log4j, or logback

Comment: I think it is always best to try to maybe fix this type of sloppy code.